# Can some please explained this code relating to Js Callback function? I am very confused with this code maybe cause I am a beginner. Questions are:

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, callback

I am very confused with this code maybe cause I am a beginner. Anyways my questions are:

1.) I did not mention videos anywhere in the code but I did mention video1, video2 and video3 in the array also I wrote a function called getUserVideos. How come in const user when I write getUserVideos(user.userEmail, videos =>{
console.log(videos);
}) it automatically shows results?

2.) Why do I need to console.log(user) twice? then again do getUserVideos(user.userEmail, videos =>{
console.log(videos);
}) ?

```js
console.log('start');

function loginUser(email, password, callback){
    setTimeout(() => {
       callback({ userEmail: email }); 
    },3000);
}

function getUserVideos(email,callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback (["video1","video2","video3"]);
  },2000)
}

const user = loginUser('labeeb@staffasia.org', 123456, user => {
  console.log(user);
  getUserVideos(user.userEmail, videos =>{
    console.log(videos);
  })
});

console.log(user);

console.log('finish');
```

A full explanation of the code will be much appreciated.

Comment: A "callback" is simply a common name given to a function that's passed to another function to be executed at a later time, usually after some processing has finished.  In this case that "later time" is a matter of a few seconds as defined by calls to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)  Instead of asking us to explain *everything* about this code, can you narrow down what you don't understand?  When you step through the code operation by operation, which one first produces an unexpected result?

Comment: Please note, that the function `loginUser` does not have an explicit return statement, so JavaScript does implicitly return `undefined` in such a case. That said, when you do `const user = loginUser` and then output the value of `user` to the console via `console.log(user)`, the result is obviously `undefined`. So the answer to your second question is: you don't need to console.log(user) twice. One time is enough, and you do it already from within the callback you pass to `loginUser` (3rd argument).

Comment: this is called [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style)

Answer (score 0):

In [a recent Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67342982/633183) I explained why Promise is the de facto choice for asynchronous control flow in modern JavaScript. Continuation-passing style, as seen in your example, is a wonderful learning exercise but there are many pitfalls and it is very difficult for beginners. This is tagged with `promise` and `async-await` so I'll show what the code would look like without continuation-passing style -

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
}

async function loginUser(email, password) {
    await sleep(3000)
    return { userEmail: email }
}

async function getUserVideos (email) {
  await sleep(2000)
  return ["video1", "video2", "video3"]
}

async function main() {
  console.log("start")
  const user = await loginUser("labeeb@staffasia.org", 123456)
  console.log(user)
  const videos = await getUserVideos(user.userEmail)
  console.log(videos)
  return "finish"
}

main().then(console.log, console.error)
```